# Saving Settings as JSON in Database vs Saving them in extra rows

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, json, database

I have settings of users, which I would like to save in the Database.
The question is now, whether or not I should make for each setting a new row, OR save them in a JSON.

What is the best way to go with, strategic- and habitwise?

Comment: If you would like to query these options i would go for record per option. Then if you would like json you could always generate json from that yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on several things:

1. How many settings do you have?
2. Do you expect them to rapidly change - both creating new settings and deleting old settings?
3. Do you need to search for users with specific settings?

Basically, JSON is more flexible and is good if you have lots of settings or if your list of settings is rapidly changing.

Fields are conservative but working with them is way faster than unpacking JSON.

Most often for user settings I would use one field per setting. The reason is that it allows easily getting a list of users with specific setting set (same age, same sex, same city etc.), also ordering them and so on.

But you can use both these options at the same time.

For example, put username, password, firstname and basic options as fields. Then you can quickly get the answers to the questions like "Is this username unique?" "is the password valid" etc.
At the same time you may create a field "additional_options" that will be json-encoded field for some not-so-often-used data, like "about me" and answers to secret questions.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a way to encode objects, or just serialize data in an easy fashion.
If you plan on saving the data and reading it not very often then JSON sounds like a good clean way, easy to upgrade later when you have more settings. If you plan on writing and reading this data a lot then you will have a big overhead of serializing and de-serializing the data and I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged as javascript, so I assume you are consuming them from js. In this case and assuming they are a small number of key-value pairs, and that you probably read them all together (ie you are not querying them individually or comparing their values for different users or things like that), then storing as json is the better option in my opinion.